# How to read binary file and insert strings to listView and each string to one line - C#

Tags: c#

I want to read binary file and insert strings to listView and each string to one line

I have made a code but i don`t know why the code is not working

```
String input = string.Empty;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog3 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog3.Filter = "bin files (*.bin)|*.bin";
if (openFileDialog3.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    if (openFileDialog3.FileName == String.Empty)
        return;

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(openFileDialog3.FileName), Encoding.Unicode);
br.BaseStream.Position = 0x8;
int Pntrnum = br.ReadInt16();
menuItem11.Visible = true;
menuItem11.Text = Pntrnum.ToString();
List<int> offsets = new List<int>();
br.BaseStream.Position = 0x10;
for (int i = 0; i < Pntrnum; i++)
{
    offsets.Add(br.ReadInt32());
}
Dictionary<int, string> values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Count; i++)
{
    int currentOffset = offsets[i];
    int nextOffset = (i + 1) < offsets.Count ? offsets[i + 1] : (int)br.BaseStream.Length;
    int stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1) / 2;
    br.BaseStream.Position = currentOffset;
    var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);
    values.Add(currentOffset, new String(chars));
}
foreach (int offset in offsets)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(offset.ToString("X")).SubItems.Add(values[offset]);
}

br.Close();
br = null;
```

Is there an other code or there is mistakes

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: When i use the program .. nothing happen .. the listview is still blank !

Comment: You should explain first *own format* of binary file: `0x8` - int16 offset length, `0x10` - array of int32 offsets, etc...

Comment: Why don't you try *debugging*? You can watch what is happening (like if you get any items in `values` or `offsets`.

Comment: Btw, do you know what `0x8` + sizeof(int16) = `0xa` (and not `0x10`) ? =D

Comment: When i use the code it appears to me ( Unable to read beyond the end of the stream ) !

Comment: Besides using a debugger, you can add some cout/printf commands and check your errors, the number of bytes you're reading, etc.